# Excel/vba: How to skip to next sheet if error?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to Find "HFM" from every worksheet and if there is one paste some names after that. So the problem is how to avoid adding the names to the sheet when there is no "HFM" in the sheet?

I first had the code without    *On Error Resume Next*   but then there is runtime error. When adding that it copies the names to all sheets. Also it returns runtime error if started from sheet that doesn't have "HFM". So how do I fix this?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets


    Cells.Find(What:="HFM", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    On Error Resume Next



    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "name1"

' etc.
```

Comment: Set the result of the `Find` method to a variable, and then afterwards, check to see if it is `Nothing` - Avoid using `On Error Resume Next` at all costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of On Error Resume Next you will have to declare a variable proceed based on result. An Example below.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
    ' Search for a text
    Set MyObjectvie = ws.Cells.Find(What:="HFM", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
            , SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not MyObjectvie Is Nothing Then
            ' if the text is found do the task
            MyObjectvie.Offset(0, 3).Value = "name1"
        End If

    Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it works only for one sheet. How to I get it to run on all sheets?

Comment: @user12646795 I have amended the code accordingly. This works.